# ¿Como utilizo un ID generado por PHP en JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, validación, modal, modalform

**Problema con los ID**

Un while me genera una tabla con los registros de la base de datos, a cada uno les asigne una ventanita modal para realizar la actualización, cada input y formulario del modal, es identificado por un ID entre la concatenacion del ID del resgitro y una palabra clave.. hasta aca todo barbaro, el problema en si es al momento de validar los inputs, ya que uso el ID para ejecutar la funcion de JavaScript y no se si puedo mezclar php dentro del codigo, de todas maneras no me funciona..

`

```
<div id="modaledit<?php print $row['id_registro']; ?>" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Auditoria manual</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <form id="formmodal<?php print $row['id_registro']; ?>" name="formmodal" action="modal_update.php" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
              <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 30px;"></div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Honorarios en Proforma: <?php print $row['HONORARIOS']; ?></label><br>
                <label>Honorarios en Factura: <?php print $row['honorarios'] ?></label><br>
              </div>
              <div class="text-left">
                <label class="col-md-6" for="hdinput">Debito de honorarios:</label>
                <input class="col-md-4" type="text" name="hdinput" id="hdinput<?php print $row['id_registro']; ?>" placeholder="<?php print $row['hondif'] ?>">
                <span id="errorhd<?php print $row['id_registro']; ?>" class="errores">Use numeros con coma</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
              <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 30px;"></div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Gastos en Proforma: <?php print $row['GASTOS']; ?></label><br>
                <label>Gastos en Factura: <?php print $row['gastos'] ?></label><br>
              </div>
              <div class="text-left">
                <label class="col-md-6" for="gdinput">Debito de gastos:</label>
                <input class="col-md-4" type="text" name="gdinput" id="gdinput" placeholder="<?php print $row['gasdif'] ?>">
                <span id="errorgd_<?php print $row['id_registro']; ?>" class="errores">Use numeros con coma</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
              <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 30px;"></div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>Materiales en Proforma: <?php print $row['MATERIAL']; ?></label><br>
                <label>Materiales en Factura: <?php print $row['materiales'] ?></label><br>
              </div>
              <div class="text-left">
                <label class="col-md-6" for="mdinput">Debito de materiales:</label>
                <input class="col-md-4" type="text" name="mdinput" id="mdinput" placeholder="<?php print $row['matdif'] ?>">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 30px;"></div>
              <?php if ($row['INTOK']=='S') {
                echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\"> Este afiliado esta internado..</div>";
              } ?>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
              <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('[name="formmodal<?php print $row['id_registro']; ?>"]').submit(function (e) {
    var HON = $('#hdinput<?php print $row['id_registro']; ?>').val();
    if (isNaN(HON)) {
      event.preventDefault(); //frenamos el envio del formulario
      $('#errorhd<?php print $row['id_registro']; ?>').css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
  });
</script>
```

`

Comment: Si se puede mezclar variables `PHP` con JS, pero en tu caso, supongo estás agregando toda esa estructura `HTML` dentro de un `while`, por lo tanto te va a generar varios script's lo cuál es un error, ahora si tu lanzas el modal con un `button, enlace(<a></a>), img, etc.` yo le pondría a esa etiqueta un atributo `data-` con un id que haga referencia al formulario en especifico que va a actualizar, p.e.: `<button data-form="formmodal<?php print $row['id_registro']; ?>">` una vez esto con js sacas en valor del atributo y con ese valor seleccionas el `form` y después sus inputs.

Comment: Además cuando seleccionas el `form` lo estás haciendo por `name` cuando en realidad es por su `id` `$('#formmodal...')...`.

Comment: jajaja ese es mi error lo llame por el nombre en vez del id, gracias!!

Comment: Que bueno que haya sido eso xD